# How do I get rid of blank screen with fixed cursor to install Ubuntu from USB drive?

Tags: screen, cursor

I need to install an app. According to the app developpers, the last Ubuntu version they explicitly mention for this app to work is 18.04.4 but the do not mention any other Ubuntu version above that one. Considering I found some problems running this app, I just need to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 to make sure the problems do not have to do with the operating system not being compatible with the app.

I already have a linux Ubuntu 18.04.5 runnning alright in an external SSD with the same computer. And I want to install Ubunut 18.04.4 now in a new SSD for the same computer.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an external SSD drive in a UEFI enabled computer from a 32GB USB stick.
I found http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/
and then I downloaded the file http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

I created a bootable USB stick with the downloaded ISO file.

When I boot with the USB stick, I select the "install" option. Then the screen goes blank with a fixed cursor symbol on the top left corner of the screen. The cursor is fixed, that means the cursor does not blink. Well, I also tried to create the USB drive with the Ubuntu ISO by means of `mkusb` and then I saw the blank screen with no curor or symbol at all.

Does anyone have any suggestion to help me install Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS?

I already tried by changing the BIOS Sata Mode from Optane without RAID to AHCI but to no avail because I still get the same black screen after selecting the option to install Ubuntu from the USB drive.

I also tried to replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` on this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmCwj.jpg) and pressing ctrl+X as suggested
at [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

but that took me to a blank screen as well.

My hardware specs are as follows:
Processor Manufacturer Intel® Processor Type Core™ i5 Processor Model i5-1035G1 Processor Speed 1 GHz Processor Core Quad-core (4 Core™) Display & Graphics Graphics Controller Manufacturer Intel® Graphics Controller Model UHD Graphics Graphics Memory Technology DDR4 SDRAM Graphics Memory Accessibility Shared Memory Standard Memory 8 GB Memory Technology DDR4 SDRAM

I also tried by installing Ubuntu 18.04.03 32 bits in the same USB stick. Then I tested this stick in an old 32 bits computer and it worked as expected. Nonetheless when I try to boot the modern 64 bits computer, the hardware specs of which I already described, with this USB stick with 32 bits Ubuntu 18.04.3, the same black screen shows up again and nothing happens after selecting "install".

By the way, I also tried to install the last version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS, with the same USB stick, and this time I did not experience the problem explained above. I guess there is a bug in the version Ubuntu 18.04.4 which I need to install. Hopefully there will be someone who has a suggestion about how to overcome this issue.

I also tried to enable secure boot and then I was able to boot from a USB stick with an image of 64 bits LXLE Ubuntu 18.04.3 but I could not boot from a USB stick with an image of the desktop version of 64 bits Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS from
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/ In this case I got the [error displayed in attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsWFO.jpg) Moreover, if I enable secure boot, then I cannot boot with the persistent install of 64 bits LXLE Ubuntu 18.04.4 I did once in an external SSD. However, if I disable secure boot then I can boot with the persistent 64 bits LXLE Ubuntu 18.04.3 of this external SSD.

Thanks

Comment: Two questions: Why 18.04 and not 20.04?  And: what kind of hardware do you have? Since you have no Linux running (where I could give you the appropriate commands) we need to know what kind of CPU and GPU you have. Since the cursor "freezes" while starting up with your USB-drive, no external hardware is involved - so changing the bios won't help..

Comment: Thanks. I just added the answers to the questions you asked within my post.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that eventually worked for me:

1. Enable secure boot in the bios settings. This was the key at least for me. With secure boot disabled I got a blank screen.
2. Boot from USB stick that has the desktop image of Ubuntu mentioned in my first message (http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/)
3. Before typing the enter key to proceed with Ubuntu install, type e. Then replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset"
4. Type F10 to boot from there.